# Symfony JSON official authenticator example

Tags: json, symfony, symfony4

Is there any official JSON authenticator example? On the guide site I find only for the Form login, the [LoginFormAuthenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html), but [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html) I do not find any example.

My problem is that I do not want to brake the built-in json authenticator in symfony, but I had to save the last login time of the user.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated after comments**

If you need to store the time of last login, you can do it using [SecurityEvents](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events)

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

class LoginEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em  = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // Subscribe to login event - fire 'storeLastLogin' method
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'storeLastLogin'
        ];
    }

    public function storeLastLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // Retrieve the User entity from token
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        // It means that you have a 'lastLogin' property in your User entity
        $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

The storing logic in 'storeLastLogin' method provided as example using Doctrine. But you free to implement it as you need.

Comment: You can use the authentication events: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events  (available for JSON authentication ??)

Comment: Right idea but unnecessarily complicated implementation.  As suggested in the previous comment, just listen for the INTERACTIVE_LOGIN event.  Especially since the posted code leaves out how to determine the current user and I'm pretty sure it does not distinguish between failed logins and successful logins.  And the VIEW event is not always fired.  If you were going to do something like this then listen for the RESPONSE event.

Comment: I agree with INTERACTIVE_LOGIN event

Comment: @RomanLitvinov You might not be aware of this but there is an edit link under your answer and no time limits for making changes.  You might consider updating your listener code.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Custom Authentication System with Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) is what you need. You will need to adapt the API-token-specific parts to your use case (and look also at the form authenticator).

Re: the last login time of the user, this is something that should be defined in your `User` class, and retrieved from the database (or users file) along with the username, roles, etc. You should write a `User::getLastLoginTime()` method, and then in your authenticator, you can call `$user->getLastLoginTime()` if you need to. (I'm curious why your authenticator needs to know the last login time though.)

**Edit:** I think I may have misunderstood your question, after reading Roman Litvinov's informative answer.